# How to express permutation as the least number of exchanges

Tags: combinatorics, permutation

*If there are grammatical or terminological errors in the following description, please help correct:*

In some problems, it is necessary to find out what minimum number of exchanges can change a list into another list.

For example, if list `{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` becomes List `{3, 4, 5, 1, 2, a, b, c}`, we need at least to swap the positions of `a` and `3`,`b` and `4`,`c` and `5`. I want to get this result: `{1->6,2->7,3->8}`(position exchange information).

```
 FindPermutation[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, a, b, c}]
```

But the result returned above is in the form of `Cycles`. what can I do to get the desired result?

*This knowledge point is very common when finding the inverse ordinal number of the arrangement in linear algebra.*

**Other examples for testing:**

```
  FindPermutation[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, a, 5, b, c}] 
(*the answer should be in the form of {1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 5 -> 7}, but I'm not sure if it is the shortest*)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some *undocumented* functionality you can use for the purpose:

```
exchanges[v1_, v2_] := Select[MapIndexed[First[#2] -> #1 &, 
                                         LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`PermutationToPivot[
                                         InversePermutation[PermutationList[
                                         FindPermutation[v1, v2]]]]], Apply[Unequal]]
```

For instance,

```
exchanges[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, a, b, c}]
   {1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8}

exchanges[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, a, 5, b, c}]
   {1 -> 4, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 7, 5 -> 7, 6 -> 8}
```

Answer (score 6):

The following should give you valid permutations, though I am not sure whether they are always minimal. At least for your second example I get the same number of swaps.

```
Swaps[orig_, final_] := 
 Rule @@@ (Sequence@@Partition[#,2,1]& /@ First@FindPermutation[final, orig])
```

```
Swaps[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1->6,2->7,3->8}
> ```

```
Swaps[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 2, 3, 4, a, 5, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1->4,4->7,7->2,2->5,3->6,6->8}
> ```

```
Swaps[{a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 2, a, 1, b, c}]
```

> ```
> {1->6,6->4,4->5,2->7,3->8}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

My first attempt at an answer was abysmally bad, and this (as a Community wiki) is merely a personal take on the [neat answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/227997/106) given by [Hausdorff](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/73380/hausdorff)

```
  swaps=Partition[#,2,1]&/@
    First@InversePermutation[FindPermutation[start, want2]]//Catenate
```

> {{1, 4}, {4, 7}, {7, 2}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}, {6, 8}}

The individual swaps may be visualized as follows:

```
 FoldList[Permute[#,Cycles[{#2}]] &, start, swaps]//TeXForm
```

$$
\left(
              \begin{array}{cccccccc}
               a & b & c & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
               1 & b & c & a & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
               1 & b & c & 4 & 2 & 3 & a & 5 \\
               1 & a & c & 4 & 2 & 3 & b & 5 \\
               1 & 2 & c & 4 & a & 3 & b & 5 \\
               1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & a & c & b & 5 \\
               1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & a & 5 & b & c \\
              \end{array}
              \right)
$$

where

```
start={a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
want2={1, 2, 3, 4, a, 5, b, c};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `PermutationList` to convert the permutation from cycle format to a list format.

Define the input and output lists

```
list1 = {a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
list2 = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, a, b, c};
```

Compute the permutation associated to go from `list1` to `list2` in cycle form.

`permcyc = FindPermutation[list1, list2]`

Now convert the permutation to list form with `PermutationList`

`permlst = PermutationList[permcyc]`

Finally, you could use `Thread`to illustrate the position exchange information:

```
Thread[Range[Length[list1]] -> permlst]
{1 -> 6, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 8, 4 -> 4, 5 -> 5, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 3}
```